# Laravel 5.3 Migration Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: migration, laravel-5.3

I have this problem when I'm runn migration iv got this error "  [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `projecto_app`.`#sql-118c_1d` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly
   formed") (SQL: alter table `parks` add constraint `parks_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`) on delete c
  ascade)"

The **users** Table is creating first second is creating table **Parks**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateParksTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('parks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id');
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->string('address',100);
            $table->string('post-code',6);
            $table->string('city',20);
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        });

    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('parks');
    }
}
```

The filenames are:
2017_01_12_000000_create_users_table
2017_02_09_111834_create_parks_table

So you can see that user table tkat have PK is earlier than Parks that need FK user_is.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you got your answer by now. 
For other people who are still looking form this solution, one of the reason this may happen is that, when you create migrations, the files are tagged with the creation date **2017_05_05_042553_create_parks_table.php**. 
in this case since the **parks** is dependent on the **users** table, just rename the **user** and change the creation date to any date before the creation date of the parks table.

Answer (score 0):

I had changed `Laravel` default `users` table name to `user`. So after I changed it in migration files and the ran `php artisan migrate` solved that issue on my end.